# Setting up if cell is blank don't continue... and show a message

Tags: excel, vba

This code works perfectly. I only have one question, I want to make it so that if there is nothing in cell Q23 that it will not put anything into NCMR Data, and say something... the code is below of what I have, and below it is what I think I need to do to a specific section to work, can someone review and make sure I am on the right path?

```
Option Explicit

Sub NCMR()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Internal NCMR
    Dim wsInt As Worksheet
    Dim wsNDA As Worksheet

    'Copy Ranges
    Dim c As Variant

    'Paste Ranges
    Dim P As Range

    'Setting Sheet
    Set wsInt = Sheets("NCMR Input")
    Set wsNDA = Sheets("NCMR Data")
    Set P = wsInt.Range("B61:V61")

    With wsInt
        c = Array(.Range("B11"), .Range("B14"), .Range("B17"), .Range("B20"), .Range("Q23"), .Range("B23") _
                , .Range("Q11"), .Range("Q14"), .Range("Q17"), .Range("Q20"), .Range("R26"), .Range("V23") _
                , .Range("V25"), .Range("V27"), .Range("B32"), .Range("B40"), .Range("B46"), .Range("B52") _
                , .Range("D58"), .Range("L58"), .Range("V58"))
    End With

    For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
        P(i + 1).Value = c(i).Value
    Next

    With wsNDA
        Dim LastRow As Long

        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        wsInt.Rows("61").Copy

        With .Rows(LastRow)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End With

        With .Range("A" & LastRow)
            If LastRow = 3 Then
                .Value = 1
            Else
                .Value = Val(wsNDA.Range("A" & LastRow - 1).Value) + 1
            End If

            .NumberFormat = "0#######"
        End With
    End With

    With Application
        .Range("A61:V61").ClearContents
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

What I want to do I think:

```
With wsInt
    Dim f As Range

    Set f = .Cell("Q23")

        If IsEmpty(f) Then
            MsgBox "The data can't entered, you have not entered any data into the Sales Order field."
        Else
                    c = Array(.Range("B11"), .Range("B14"), .Range("B17"), .Range("B20"), .Range("Q23"), .Range("B23") _
                , .Range("Q11"), .Range("Q14"), .Range("Q17"), .Range("Q20"), .Range("R26"), .Range("V23") _
                , .Range("V25"), .Range("V27"), .Range("B32"), .Range("B40"), .Range("B46"), .Range("B52") _
                , .Range("D58"), .Range("L58"), .Range("V58"))
        End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe as simple as:

```
With wsInt 
    If Len(.Range("Q23")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The data can't be entered, you have not entered any data into the Sales Order field."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With      'added this line for clarity
```

Comment: What does If Len do? Also what is the use of Dim f as Range is there is no need for it?

Comment: Also, no go... won't submit     `If Len(.Cell("Q23")) = 0 Then` I get an error here. A compile Error, Method or Data Member can't be found.

Comment: LEN() returns the length of the entry in the cell.  My preferred 'isempty' approach.  The Dim F is not needed, I just moved it out, removed it now.  I also edited the code above to use the .Range() syntax

Comment: Just tried, I'm getting an error: expected End With. Here is the code I have now: `With wsInt
        If Len(.Range("Q23")) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The data can't be entered, you have not entered any data into the Sales Order field."
        Exit Sub
    End If
        c = Array()
    End With`

Comment: Yes, I gave you a snippet, you need to construct your entire module or test module correctly.  If you're testing JUST what I gave, you do need to an END WITH statement to close off the With wsInt section. *(see above)*